# Use Wepack for Client only in strongloop-loopback

Tags: vue.js, webpack, strongloop, loopback

I want to use webpack bundling for only client part of Strongloop Loopback project (I want to use vueJs in client or frontend). I've been looking at loopback-webpack-plugin. As there is no proper documentation for it, I am unable to use in way I wanted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to write your client in VueJS, the configuration of your build process for the client is going to be pretty much independent of LoopBack. Please look for resources on how to configure Webpack for VueJS.

There is one part relevant to LoopBack though: how to serve you VueJS front-end files from a LoopBack application. In a typical LoopBack project scaffolded via [`lb`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-cli), the client (front-end) assets created by Webpack should be placed in the `client` directory. See [Adding a static web page](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Add-a-static-web-page.html) in LoopBack's documentation to learn how to expose the content of the `client` directory as a web application.